# How to call a non static method of controller in spring only once whenever my application gets started

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and being stuck with a problem.

I have to call a method only once after my application gets started. is there is any annotation for that. I don't want to use init config and  @PostConstruct because for that I need to create an object of the bean. My method should get called only once as soon as my application gets started.

I am using Spring MVC 3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it's a non-`static` method, then you need an instance to invoke the method on. If the instance depends on beans in the context, then the appropriate way is to define a bean for it and use `@PostConstruct`. If the instance doesn't have any dependencies on the `ApplicationContext`, just create it yourself and call its method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your context is loading in the start up. You can use this to do that

```
<bean name="YOUR_BEAN_NAME" init-method="YOUR_METHOD_NAME" class="YOUR_CLASS_NAME" lazy="false" />
```